# What the name of the technique?

Tags: statistics, data-mining

I have a raw log file and I would like to extract relationships/behavioral patterns between events.

But important point that I do not have ActivityId/GroupId/SessionId which I can cluster them (referring to process mining), so it can start at any moment in log and end at any moment.

My question is what kind of techniques available to extract behavioral states from log like this:

```
t1, event1
t2, event2
t2, event3
t3, event4
...
t5, event11
```

t[N] - is time, and periodicity is not constant (one event can happen in 1 minute, next one can be in 5 minutes, then 4 events can happens in same time after 20 minutes)

where I could say give me all possible sequences which leads to event10.

Ideally I would like something what can produce following outcome, something what could be later described as many different state machines (means some events could be skipped in between, and I wait only for condition I care about):

```
event5 -> event6 -> event7
event2 -> (NOT event6 + event7) -> event10
event1 -> (event8 + event9) -> (event10+event11) -> even13
```

what would be the possible techniques to extract this from stream of events?
Most of the stuff I know looking into data from perspective of bags-of-events and then searching similar patterns inside bags, but what if I do not have this grouping but still want to extract some process/patterns repeated?

Answer (score 0):

Frequent Sequence Mining.

A variant of frequent itemset mining hat takes temporal order into account.

Comment: But do I need to have sequence-id? or can be stream of events without any identifier? Most of the examples has CID(sequence-id).

Comment: That's right, usually these approaches use a set of sequences. But I'd assume literature mentions some ways of dealing with this. I guess it requires some tradeoffs such as using sliding windows.

Comment: Uhh, ok, thank you. My original question was to find out it there any technique that is not required any assumptions (like rolling window size, etc...). Because to define correct windows size is another story challenge :)

Comment: I don't know what these methods use. But it's fairly obvious that you do need to make *some* assumptions / restrictions on what an admissible solution is, if you don't want to just find everything.

Comment: For example, that sequences do not overlap. Then you could simply split your data after every "event10" if that is what you are most interested in.